# Use HTML tags inside UILabel

Tags: ios, json, swift

I've got this JSON that has some HTML tags inside of it.

```
"activities": [
        {
            "message": "<strong>Henrik</strong> didn't resist a guilty pleasure at <strong>Starbucks</strong>."

        },
        {
            "message": "<strong>Johan</strong> made a roundup."
        },
        {
            "message": "<strong>You</strong> didn't resist a guilty pleasure at <strong>Starbucks</strong>."
        },
        {
            "message": "<strong>Daniel</strong> made a roundup."
        },
]
```

And I want to use the message field to display on an UILabel, like:

```
cell.descriptionLabel.text = activity.message
```

How can I do this?

Update, I used:

```
let messageString = activity.message
        let htmlData = NSString(string: messageString).data(using: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
        let options = [NSAttributedString.DocumentReadingOptionKey.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html]
        let attributedString = try! NSAttributedString(data: htmlData!,
                                                       options: options,
                                                       documentAttributes: nil)
        cell.descriptionLabel.attributedText = attributedString
```

But now the UILabel is all in Times New Roman, don't know why. How can I change it back to the default font?

Comment: Look for "NSAttributedString + HTML".

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response! I did it but I have a minor issue now, please check the edit.

Comment: The simplest way is to add a html tag around your message where you set the font you want.